# How can I return rows that meet a specific sequence of events?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to pull records for UserIDs that meet a certain sequence of events. If a user has a JOIN, then a subsequent CANCEL, and then a subsequent JOIN, I want to return them in the result set. I need to run this query for one day at a time, or several days at a time, as needed.

The table below shows examples of UserIDs that meet and do not meet the sequence.

```
+--------+--------+---------------------+------------+------------------+
| rownum | UserID |      Timestamp      | ActionType | Return in query? |
+--------+--------+---------------------+------------+------------------+
|      1 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:25:39 | JOIN       | yes              |
|      2 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:27:00 | NULL       | yes              |
|      3 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:28:20 | DOWNGRADE  | yes              |
|      4 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:31:34 | NULL       | yes              |
|      5 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:32:44 | CANCEL     | yes              |
|      6 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:45:51 | NULL       | yes              |
|      7 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:50:57 | JOIN       | yes              |
|      1 |   9876 | 2016-11-01 16:05:42 | JOIN       | yes              |
|      2 |   9876 | 2016-11-01 16:07:33 | CANCEL     | yes              |
|      3 |   9876 | 2016-11-01 16:09:09 | JOIN       | yes              |
|      1 |  56565 | 2016-11-01 18:15:16 | JOIN       | no               |
|      2 |  56565 | 2016-11-01 19:22:25 | CANCEL     | no               |
|      3 |  56565 | 2016-11-01 20:05:05 | CANCEL     | no               |
|      1 |  34343 | 2016-11-01 05:32:56 | JOIN       | no               |
+--------+--------+---------------------+------------+------------------+
```

I have read up on gaps and islands, and looked at all sorts of complicated forum posts that dance around what I'm trying to achieve.

Currently, all I'm able to do is look at one day's worth of records, with no constraint on the sequence logic that I need:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY tmsmp) rownum
    ,UserID
    ,tmstmp
    ,ActionType
FROM
    t
    INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT UserID
                FROM t
                WHERE tmstmp BETWEEN '2016-11-20 00:00:01' AND '2016-11-20 11:59:59'
                GROUP BY UserID
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
                ) AS sub ON t1.UserID = sub.UserID
```

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Do the three records need to be in order?  That is, can there be gaps or do you want JOIN/CANCEL/JOIN with no gaps?

Comment: The returned rows do not need to be in the contiguous desired order in which they are plucked from the table, though I would be curious to know your thoughts on achieving both outputs to accommodate future needs. Thanks!

Comment: Just for fun, yet another solution: `select * from (select userid, string_agg(actiontype, ',' order by timestamp) /*filter (where actiontype is not null)*/ as actions from t group by userid) as u where actions like '%JOIN,CANCEL,JOIN%';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my sample queries I'll do the best I can with the information you've given, but you're a little unclear about what the source table(s) look like.  You show one table above (with no name), but then reference two different tables in your sample query... a little hard to see what's going on.

So I'll assume a single table, named `t`, and you can adjust as needed...

Then how I would handle this, is first identify the users

```
select distinct userid
  from            t first_join
       inner join t cancel
               on first_join.tmstmp < cancel.tmstp
              and first_join.userid = cancel.userid
       inner join t.second_join
               on second_join.tmstmp > cancel.tmstp
              and second_join.userid = cancel.userid
 where first_join.actiontype = 'JOIN'
   and cancel.actiontype = 'CANCEL'
   and second_join.actiontype = 'JOIN'
```

So now you can get all records for those users

```
SELECT *
  FROM T
 WHERE USERID IN (
    select distinct userid
      from            t first_join
           inner join t cancel
                   on first_join.tmstmp < cancel.tmstp
                  and first_join.userid = cancel.userid
           inner join t.second_join
                   on second_join.tmstmp > cancel.tmstp
                  and second_join.userid = cancel.userid
     where first_join.actiontype = 'JOIN'
       and cancel.actiontype = 'CANCEL'
       and second_join.actiontype = 'JOIN'
     )
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I edited my sample query from 't1' to 't' - it is referring to the same table in both main WHERE clause and INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LEAD()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.* ,
           LAG(t.ActionType,1) OVER(PARTITION BY t.userid ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS LAST_ACTION,
           LAG(t.ActionType,2) OVER(PARTITION BY t.userid ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS LAST_ACTION2,
           LEAD(t.ActionType,1) OVER(PARTITION BY t.userid ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS NEXT_Action,
           LEAD(t.ActionType,2) OVER(PARTITION BY t.userid ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS NEXT_Action2
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE tmstmp BETWEEN <Start> AND <End>)
WHERE (t.actionType = 'JOIN' AND
      t.NEXT_Action = 'Cancel' AND
      t.NEXT_Action2 = 'JOIN')
  OR (t.LAST_ACTION= 'JOIN' AND
      t.actionType= 'Cancel' AND
      t.NEXT_Action = 'JOIN')
  OR (t.LAST_ACTION2= 'JOIN' AND
      t.LAST_ACTION = 'Cancel' AND
      t.actionType= 'JOIN')
```

Comment: sagi, does this solution account for the discontinuous rows that can occur between the JOIN>CANCEL>JOIN occurrences? For example, in my sample code above, UserID has a JOIN on row 1, a CANCEL on row 5, and a JOIN on row 7. My understanding is that this will only look at the next row in sequence by virtue of the offset parameter of the lead function. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Allow me to clarify- there can be any number of ActionType values in between the JOIN, then CANCEL, then JOIN. As long as those three occur in sequence, it doesn't matter if it occurs discontinuously across 20 rows, or it occurs in sequence across 3 rows. My question is whether your solution restricts the results to only those that are 1 or 2 rows away from the first JOIN, by virtue of the LEAD function offset parameter being 1 and 2. Does that help clarify? I would be happy to provide more examples if needed. Thanks!!

Comment: Wait, if a sequence like that exists, you want only the three records with `JOIN->CANCEL->JOIN` or you want the entire userid records? @psrpsrpsr

Comment: Either/Or - I would be curious how to get both; the entire UserID recordset would be helpful for drawing patterns, and the three JOIN>CANCEL>JOIN records would be helpful for a neatly packaged description of the problem.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that the records are in order with no gaps, just use `lag()`, `lead()` or a combination:

```
select distinct userId
from (select t.*,
             lag(ActionType) over (partition by userId order by tmstamp) as prev_at,
             lead(ActionType) over (partition by userId order by tmstamp) as next_at,
      from t
     ) t
where ActionType = 'Cancel' and prev_at = 'Join' and next_at = 'Join';
```

If gaps are allowed, then you can do this differently:

```
select distint userid
from t
where ActionType = 'Cancel' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.userId = t.userId and
                    t2.at = 'Join' and
                    t2.tmstamp < t.tmstamp
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.userId = t.userId and
                    t2.at = 'Join' and
                    t2.tmstamp > t.tmstamp
             );
```