# How can I return rows that meet criteria for occurring in one day, but over a date range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query (shown below) that returns all rows for UserID that have :

1. a JOIN,
2. a subsequent CANCEL, and then
3. a subsequent JOIN

**But: I need to return UserIDs that meet this criteria of having a JOIN,CANCEL, then JOIN in sequence *ON THE SAME DAY*, but for a date range: for example BETWEEN 2016-11-01 and 2016-11-30. So in the example table below, UserIDs 12345, 9876, and 33445 would be returned.**

I'm not sure how this is achieved - would be involve some sort of grouping on the timestamp date? Would a stored procedure that iterates over conditional tests for UserID and ActionType be a viable solution?

```
+--------+--------+----------------------+------------+------------------+
| rownum | UserID |      Timestamp       | ActionType | Return in query? |
+--------+--------+----------------------+------------+------------------+
|      1 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:25:39  | JOIN       | yes              |
|      2 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:27:00  | NULL       | yes              |
|      3 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:28:20  | DOWNGRADE  | yes              |
|      4 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:31:34  | NULL       | yes              |
|      5 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:32:44  | CANCEL     | yes              |
|      6 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:45:51  | NULL       | yes              |
|      7 |  12345 | 2016-11-01 08:50:57  | JOIN       | yes              |

|      1 |   9876 | 2016-11-01 16:05:42  | JOIN       | yes              |
|      2 |   9876 | 2016-11-01 16:07:33  | CANCEL     | yes              |
|      3 |   9876 | 2016-11-01 16:09:09  | JOIN       | yes              |

|      1 |  56565 | 2016-11-01 18:15:16  | JOIN       | no               |
|      2 |  56565 | 2016-11-01 19:22:25  | CANCEL     | no               |
|      3 |  56565 | 2016-11-01 20:05:05  | CANCEL     | no               |

|      1 |  34343 | 2016-11-01 05:32:56  | JOIN       | no               |

                        NEXT DAY

|      1 |   7878 | 2016-11-02 10:05:04  | JOIN       | no               |
|      2 |   7878 | 2016-11-02 10:06:06  | JOIN       | no               |

|      1 |  33445 | 2016-11-02 02:33:34  | JOIN       | yes              |
|      2 |  33445 | 2016-11-02 02:33:34  | NULL       | yes              |
|      3 |  33445 | 2016-11-02 02:37:56  | CANCEL     | yes              |
|      4 |  33445 | 2016-11-02 02:38:01  | JOIN       | yes              |
+--------+--------+----------------------+------------+------------------+
```

Here is a link to the question which led me to the query that pulls data for exactly one day (not a range): [How can I return rows that meet a specific sequence of events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766930/how-can-i-return-rows-that-meet-a-specific-sequence-of-events)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM T
 WHERE USERID IN (
    select distinct userid
      from            t first_join
           inner join t cancel
                   on first_join.tmstmp < cancel.tmstp
                  and first_join.userid = cancel.userid
           inner join t.second_join
                   on second_join.tmstmp > cancel.tmstp
                  and second_join.userid = cancel.userid
     where first_join.actiontype = 'JOIN'
       and cancel.actiontype = 'CANCEL'
       and second_join.actiontype = 'JOIN'
     )
```

Clarification of comments/questions:
vkp:

1. QUESTION: can join,cancel,join be on different days with other values in between? ANSWER: No, I need to find the join>cancel>join that occur in one day only. If there is a join on 11/1 and a cancel on 11/2, that UserID does not need to be returned.
2. QUESTION: if a particular date satisfies cancel,join,cancel in the date range, will that be enough for a user to be included in the results? ANSWER: No, I am specifically looking at rows that meet the ActionType sequence in one day, not over a range of days.

**THANK YOU!**

Comment: couple of things need clarification..1) can join,cancel,join be on different days with other values in between? 2) if a particular date satisfies cancel,join,cancel in the date range..will that be enough for a user to be included in the results?

Comment: Edited question to include answers - please let me know if you need any further clarification. Short answers: no, and no. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the users and the days when they have the specified sequence of events happen, use

```
select distinct userid,tmstamp::date
from t
where ActionType = 'CANCEL' and tmstamp::date between date '2016-11-01' and date '2016-11-30' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.userId = t.userId and
                    t2.actiontype = 'JOIN' and
                    t2.tmstamp < t.tmstamp and 
                    t2.tmstamp::date = t.tmstamp::date
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t3
              where t3.userId = t.userId and
                    t3.actiontype = 'JOIN' and
                    t3.tmstamp > t.tmstamp and
                    t3.tmstamp::date = t.tmstamp::date
             )
```

To get all the rows for such users on those days, wrap the previous query as a subquery against the original table.

```
select * from t where (userid,tmstamp::date) in (
select distinct userid,tmstamp::date
from t
where ActionType = 'CANCEL' 
and tmstamp::date between date '2016-11-01' and date '2016-11-30' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.userId = t.userId and
                    t2.actiontype = 'JOIN' and
                    t2.tmstamp < t.tmstamp and 
                    t2.tmstamp::date = t.tmstamp::date
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t3
              where t3.userId = t.userId and
                    t3.actiontype = 'JOIN' and
                    t3.tmstamp > t.tmstamp and
                    t3.tmstamp::date = t.tmstamp::date
             )
    )
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/JMN71501)**

Note that this is a minor tweak to @Gordon's query (to check for these sequence of events on a particular day) in your previous question which i felt was the best.

Edit: An alternate approach with window functions

```
select * from t where (userid,tmstamp::date) in (
    select distinct userid,tmstamp::date from (
    select t.*
    ,min(case when actiontype = 'JOIN' then 1 else 2 end) over(partition by t.userid,t.tmstamp::date order by t.tmstamp rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) min_before
    ,min(case when actiontype = 'JOIN' then 1 else 2 end) over(partition by t.userid,t.tmstamp::date order by t.tmstamp rows between 1 following and unbounded following) min_after
    from (select userid,tmstamp from t where actiontype='CANCEL') tc
    join t on t.userid=tc.userid and t.tmstamp::date=tc.tmstamp::date
    ) x 
    where min_before=1 and min_after=1
        )
```

1) Using a `case` expression we designate all actiontype `JOIN` rows as 1 and 2 for all other actiontypes.

2) We `join` it with the actiontype `CANCEL` rows.

3) Then we check for the minimum value before `CANCEL` and minimum value after `CANCEL` for each date and userid combination. Per the `case` expression defined, it should be 1.

4) Get all such dates and userid's and fetch the corresponding rows.

Comment: Ah - so by adding the t2.tmstamp::date = t.tmstamp::date to the WHERE clause of the EXISTS conditions ensures that the scope of the ActionType sequences is on one day only - am I understanding that correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Much appreciated!